# How to store the payload at any point to use it later

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I've deployed spring-cloud-dataflow with Docker. These are the used containers:

- springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local:1.7.0.RELEASE
- wurstmeister/zookeeper
- wurstmeister/kafka:1.1.0

[other containers not involved in the issue ...]

Documentation consulted:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.7.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

---

> I am trying to create a stream in which i need to store the payload to use it later.

[image]

> ```
> http | groovy-transform | httpclient_get: httpclient | httpclient_post: httpclient | log
> ```

**There is some way to solve this need?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear from your generic description what the best approach would be. A couple of options:

1. Fan out to the get and post

   `http | groovy-transform > :request`
   `:request > httpclient-get |log`
   `:request > httpclient-post|log`

The streams can be joined:

```
 http | groovy-transform > :request     
 :request > httpclient-get > :response     
 :request > httpclient-post > :response
 :response > log
```

2. Use a [Header enricher](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/header-enricher/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-header-enricher/README.adoc) processor to add the original payload as a header along with some code to extract the header in httpclient_post.

Note if you are using the kafka binder with kafka < 0.11 client, you need to explicitly enable [custom headers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_binder_properties): For example:

```
stream create hetest --definition "time | header-enricher --headers=foo='bar' | log --expression=headers"    
stream deploy hetest --properties "app.*.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headers=foo"
```

Comment: Hello @dturanski,

Thanks for your time. I tried option one above to ask my question, but that option does not solve my problem because the flow will be separated into two other flows and there is no mechanism to join them again after they perform their work and the result is a single message.

Comment: Hello @dturanski,

Also try option 2, but the Header-Enricher processor does not work as I thought and the documentation is not very good, and we do not have any examples of its use.

When I used it I thought that the variables' foo = bar 'or foo =' bar 'or' foo = bar 'or' foo = 'bar' "or 'foo = \" bar \ "' that were declared in the processor were for persist in the flow until the end or, at least, until the next step, but when using a record later with #root or #root.header, my variable did not exist anywhere.

Comment: For option 1, you can join the two streams. I have edited the response to illustrate.

Comment: Hello @dturanski option 2 works fine and solves my problem, thank you very much.